# Roasting Par boiled Vegetables

Tags: vegetables, roasting

I parboiled zucchini broccoli cauliflower carrots and butternut squash now I want to roast them in the oven what temperature and how long should I roast them since they're partially cooked?

Answer (score 4):

We don't know how cooked your items are after the par boil.  It also depends on the size of the items.  So, we can't be very precise here.  I would use high heat (400F or higher) because you probably want some color before the items overcook.  As soon as they have some color, test for done-ness.  Zucchini cooks much faster than the other items, so you might add that when the other items are almost complete.

Comment: It might even be worth putting them under the broiler to get the color on the outside without cooking the middle too much more

Comment: ...yes...what@Joe says....

Answer (score 0):

I would not par boil zucchini, they will be over cooked and mushy

par boil just enough that the vegetables are starting to be tender; stick a for in them.

Remove from the water and make sure you drain them completely, or as close to. Put them on a sheet pan and less the steam steam away.

Toss with olive oil and seasoning and put in an high temperature oven (400F+)

The high temperature is kinda required to remove as much humidity as quickly as possible so the vegetables can get some colors.

You have to keep an eye on them.